# Vectorized way of checking a date column's calendar sequence

Tags: python, pandas, date, vectorization

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
   Market Date  Begin Date  Settlement
0   2016-01-01  2016-01-01  26.1935
1   2016-01-01  2016-02-01  24.1071
2   2016-01-01  2016-03-01  21.0591
3   2016-01-01  2016-04-01  20.7348
4   2016-01-01  2016-05-01  20.2072
... ... ... ...
265198  2022-09-21  2031-04-01  65.1300
265199  2022-09-21  2031-05-01  65.1300
265200  2022-09-21  2031-06-01  65.1300
265201  2022-09-21  2031-07-01  65.1300
265202  2022-09-21  2031-08-01  65.1300
```

I wish to change the values of settlement to zero, if the Begin Date doesn't have data for the entire year.

example output:

```
   Market Date  Begin Date  Settlement
0   2016-01-01  2018-01-01  0
1   2016-01-01  2018-02-01  0
2   2016-01-01  2019-01-01  15.2789
3   2016-01-01  2019-02-01  20.7348
4   2016-01-01  2019-03-01  26.1552
5   2016-01-01  2019-04-01  24.1891
6   2016-01-01  2019-05-01  21.7891
7   2016-01-01  2019-06-01  20.7356
8   2016-01-01  2019-07-01  20.2072
9   2016-01-01  2019-08-01  20.2172
10  2016-01-01  2019-09-01  20.2272
11  2016-01-01  2019-10-01  20.2372
12  2016-01-01  2019-11-01  20.2572
13  2016-01-01  2019-12-01  20.2772
14  2016-02-01  2019-01-01  0
15  2016-02-01  2020-01-01  20.25
```

Note I have full data for 1st Feb 2016 for the year 2020. I just did not post it here.

For this problem, I don't want to essentially do a row wise iteration because of obvious reasons. Is there a more Pythonic way of doing it?

Comment: What do you mean by "*Begin Date doesn't have data for the entire year*"?

Comment: In the output example, notice how begin date does not have data for the entire year of 2018, just the first two months, which is why settlement is zero. Meant that.

Comment: You were on the right track, your code snippet works fine once modified, like this: `df.loc[df.groupby([df['Market Date'].dt.year, df['Begin Date'].dt.year])["Settlement"].transform("count") < 12, "Settlement"] = 0`. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you so much, that’s a real help!